# Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) save to file is not saving on iOS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

We are unable to successfully write data on an iOS app using this KMP code.  We would like to know what we can change to make it write successfully:

```
suspend fun HttpResponse.saveBodyToFile(fileSystem: FileSystem, outputFile: Path): Boolean {
    var success = false
    try {
        // if the target file already exists, remove it.
        fileSystem.delete(outputFile)

        val parentDir = outputFile.parent ?: return false
        if (!fileSystem.exists(parentDir)) {
            fileSystem.createDirectories(parentDir)
        }

        val byteReadChannel: ByteReadChannel = body()
        fileSystem.sink(outputFile).buffer().use {
            byteReadChannel.readFully(it)
        }

        success = fileSystem.exists(outputFile)
    } catch (e: KtorIoException) {
        Logger.e(e) { "Failed to save response stream to ${outputFile.name}" }
        Logger.e { "I/O Exception ${e.message}"}
       fileSystem.delete(outputFile)
    } catch (e: OkioIOException) {
        Logger.e { "I/O Exception ${e.message}"}
        Logger.e(e) { "Failed to save response stream to ${outputFile.name}" }
        Logger.e { "I/O Exception ${e.message}"}
        fileSystem.delete(outputFile)
    }
    return success
}
```

Strangely enough it creates a directory, but throws this error:
 I/O Exception Read-only file system

If the directory already exists, it still evaluates this as true:

```
(!fileSystem.exists(parentDir))
```

and tries to create it again.

If the directory exists, and this section of code is commented out:

```
 if (!fileSystem.exists(parentDir)) {
    fileSystem.createDirectories(parentDir)
 }
```

then this section of code:

```
fileSystem.sink(outputFile).buffer().use {
    byteReadChannel.readFully(it)
}
```

throws this error:
 I/O Exception Read-only file system

We are passing in a subdirectory of the Cache directory:

```
file:/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85FF4164-D3CF-446C-AF42-EC64B5473BCA/data/Containers/Data/Application/7F890ECD-83DB-4D91-8BBD-102F631594A6/Library/Caches/syncFiles/sync-proxy.json
```

Comment: I don't know if your process has write access to that folder (from the error I would guess not). Are you creating the folder, or only failing to detect that it exists? In any case, I would use one of the predefined folders on iOS where you can save things (example: https://github.com/touchlab/SQLiter/blob/main/sqliter-driver/src/appleMain/kotlin/co/touchlab/sqliter/DatabaseFileContext.kt#L39). There are other directory options, but not sure what you need: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssearchpathdirectory/nsapplicationsupportdirectory

Comment: I've also tried the documents folder as shown in that sqlite sample, and get the same result..  And my iOS app (the non-Kotlin portion) can successfully write to both the cache directory and the documents directory.  This Kotlin stuff creates a directory in the cache folder, so it is writing something, but even as it creates the directory, it throws the read-only error.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to create `expect class` wrapper for all file operations with platform-specific code in `actual` classes. Such low level access to FS may be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we are using Okio for KMP I/O operations. To access the appropriate directory

```
guard let cacheDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("syncFiles")
```

Than passing `cacheDirectory.absoluteString` as the parent directory to okio's filesystem. `absoluteString` returns a string in the form of `file:<path>`

Okio uses `lstat` to determine if a path exists. `lstat` does not support url formated paths, whereas okio does support url formatted file paths.

When `createDirectories` is called it uses `lstat` which returns false to okio and it will try to create all the parent directories which already exist and are read only causing the crash.

The fix is quite simple instead of calling `cacheDirectory.absoluteString` change it to `cacheDirectory.path()` which removes the `file:` and `lstat` reports back correctly.